# Distribution of $X_n$ Stochastic process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

[image]

I am thinking of finding $P(X_3=r|X_0=s)$ i.e $P_{s,r}^3$. But with the given data i am unable to go ahead.
Am I thinking correctly? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the initial distribution $\mu$ , i.e. $\mu = (0.5, 0.5, 0)$. In your lecture notes you should have a formula like this
$$ P_\mu(X_n = x) = P^n \mu$$
(maybe read up on that a bit) hence you should do something like $P^2 * \mu$. I hope you can figure out why the exponent is two here, rather than three.